# React class Component not re render after props change from redux action

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

The component does not re render after successfully update state in redux
i have tried to do some condition in componentShouldUpdate end up with loading true without change

reducer.js

```
 import * as types from "./actionsType";

    const INITIAL_STATE = {
       slide_data: [],
       error: null,
       loading: false,
    };

        const updateObject = (oldObject, updatedProperties) => {
           return {
         ...oldObject,
        ...updatedProperties,
      };
    };
const slideReducer = (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case types.SLIDES_FETCH_START:
      return updateObject(state, {
        error: null,
        loading: true,
      });
    case types.SLIDES_FETCH_SUCSSES:
      return updateObject(state, {
        slide_data: action.payload,
        error: null,
        loading: false,
      });
    case types.SLIDES_FETCH_FAIL:
      return updateObject(state, {
        error: action.error,
        loading: false,
      });
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default slideReducer;
```

actions.js

```
import * as types from "./actionsType";
import axios from "axios";
import { selectSlides } from "./slides.selectors";
export const slidesStart = () => {
  return {
    type: types.SLIDES_FETCH_START,
  };
};

export const slidesSucces = (slides) => {
  return {
    type: types.SLIDES_FETCH_SUCSSES,
    payload: slides,
  };
};

export const slidesFail = (error) => {
  return {
    type: types.SLIDES_FETCH_FAIL,
    error: error,
  };
};

export const fetchSlides = () => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    console.log("fetch Start");
    dispatch(slidesStart());
    axios
      .get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/slides/", {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
      })
      .then((res) => {
        dispatch(slidesSucces(res.data));
      })
      .catch((err) => dispatch(slidesFail(err)));
  };
};
```

component

```
class IntroPage extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.tlitRef = React.createRef();
    this.titlelRef = React.createRef();
    this.subTitleRef = React.createRef();
    this.showcase = React.createRef();
  }

componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchSlides();
}

  render() {
    const { slides, loading } = this.props;
    if (loading) {
      return <h1>Loading</h1>;
    }
    return (
      <div className="intro">
       
           
            <div className="wrapper">
              {slides.map((data) => (
                <SwiperSlides data={data} key={data.name} />
              ))}
            </div>
        
        

        
      </div>
    );
  }
}

    const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
      return {
        loading: state.slides.loading,
        error: state.slides.error,
        slides: state.slides.slide_data,
      };
    };
    
    const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
      return {
        fetchSlides: () => dispatch(fetchSlides()),
      };
    };
    export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(IntroPage);
```

Register the redux-logger correctly. The data was returned but nothing changes when I do redux-persist and try to reload data come through
[image: redux-logger console log]

update ::
when I change the size of the browser data it correctly appears what is this !!

Comment: Does `SLIDES_FETCH_SUCSSES` end up modifying the `slides_data`?

Comment: yea when i log  props in ComponentWillUnmount it's return the slides_data with a Array of 5 items

Comment: It would be easier to debug if you manage to post a codesandbox example.

Comment: A moment when I change the size of the browser data it correctly appears what is this !!

Comment: full code here https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-vaughan-p3qgs?file=/src/pages/intro-page.jsx try to resize sanbox preview and image will showing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

update : this problem related to swiperjs

and the solution will be like that:

1 - assign swiper instance to React.CreateRef(null) : this.swiper = React.CreateRef(null)

2 - in componentDidUpdate() make a swiper update : this.swiper.current.update()

4 - use a arrow function syntax in swiper on functions to refer to the outer scope